# I need the name of the enterprise to be the same as it was when it was registered and not the value it currently has

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I will explain the problem with an example:
I am designing a specific case of referential integrity in a table. In the model there are two tables, enterprise and document. We register the companies and then someone insert the documents associated with it. The name of the enterprise is variable. When it comes to recovering the documents, I need the name of the enterprise to be the same as it was when it was registered and not the value it currently has. The solution that I thought was to register the company again in each change with the same code, the updated name in this way would have the expected result, but I am not sure if it is the best solution. Can someone make a suggestion?
[image]

Comment: If it is always the original value, why not add a "OriginalName" field?

Comment: Because the name can change many times.

Comment: I understand the name can change many times but you are saying "I need the name of the enterprise to be the same as it was when it was **registered** and not the value it currently has" i.e. the original name, is it not? It is not very clear to me what all those "it" in your sentences refer to but you have used the word "register" several times, solely for the enterprise so I assumed you **register** enterprises and you **insert** documents. Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a date range to your enterprise: valid_from, valid_to. Initialise to -infinity,+infinity. When you change the name of an enterprise, instead: update existing rows where valid_to = +infinity to be now() and insert the new name with valid_from = now(), valid_to = +infinity.

Add a date field to the document, something like create_date. Then when joining to enterprise you join on ID and d.create_date between e.valid_from and e.valid_to.

This is a simplistic approach and breaks things like uniqueness for your id and code. To handle that you could record the name in a separate table with the id,from,to,name. Leaving your original table with just the id and code for uniqueness.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions and it is hard to determine which one will exactly be the easiest.

**Side comment**: your question is limited to managing names efficiently but I would like to comment the fact that your DB is sensitive to files being moved, renamed or deleted. Your database will not be able to keep records up-to-date if anything happen at OS level. You should consider to do something about it too.

Amongst the few solution I considered, the one that is best normalized is the schema below:

```
CREATE TABLE Enterprise
(
    IdEnterprise SERIAL     PRIMARY KEY
,   Code         VARCHAR(4) UNIQUE
,   IdName       INTEGER  DEFAULT -1 /* This will be used to get a single active name */
);
CREATE TABLE EnterpriseName (
    IDName       SERIAL     PRIMARY KEY
,   IdEnterprise INTEGER    NOT NULL REFERENCES Enterprise(IdEnterprise) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
,   Name         TEXT       NOT NULL
);
ALTER TABLE Enterprise ADD FOREIGN KEY (IdName) REFERENCES EnterpriseName(IdName) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED;
CREATE TABLE Document
(
    IdDocument   SERIAL     PRIMARY KEY
,   IdName       INTEGER    NOT NULL REFERENCES EnterpriseName(IDName) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
,   FilePath     TEXT       NOT NULL
,   Description  TEXT
);
```

Using flag and/or timestamps or moving the enterprise name to the `document` table are appealing solutions, but only at first glance.
Especially, the part where you have to ensure a company always has 1, and 1 only "active" name is no easy thing to do.

Comment: Let me know if you do not see how data is selected/inserted/updated/deleted